# Помогите найти ошибку (детерминант)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Здравствуйте. Пробую написать расчет детерминанты матрицы методом разложения. Прикладываю текст программы и вывод командной строки. Python 3.5

```
def cutmtrx(y, mtrx):
    for i in range(len(mtrx[0])):
        mtrx[i].pop(y)
    mtrx.pop(0)
    return mtrx

def deter(n, mtrx):
if n == 2:
    return mtrx[0][0]*mtrx[1][1]-mtrx[0][1]*mtrx[1][0]
elif n >= 3:
    x = 0
    mn = 1
    for i in range(n):
        x += mn*mtrx[0][i]*deter(n-1, cutmtrx(i, mtrx))
        mn *= -1
    return x

n = int(input())
mtrx = []
for i in range(n):
    mtrx.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
print(deter(n, mtrx))
```

Вывод:

```
    C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Python>python determinant.py
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "determinant.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(deter(n, mtrx))
  File "determinant.py", line 15, in deter
    m = deter(n-1, mt)
  File "determinant.py", line 9, in deter
    return mtrx[0][0]*mtrx[1][1]-mtrx[0][1]*mtrx[1][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Python>python determinant.py
3
1 5 9
4 7 3
2 5 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "determinant.py", line 22, in <module>
print(deter(n, mtrx))
  File "determinant.py", line 14, in deter
    x += mn*mtrx[0][i]*deter(n-1, cutmtrx(i, mtrx))
  File "determinant.py", line 9, in deter
    return mtrx[0][0]*mtrx[1][1]-mtrx[0][1]*mtrx[1][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 3):

Массивы в python передаются по ссылке. Функция `cutmtrx` портит массив `mtrx`, после первого обращения он становится 2x2 после второго 1x1, это и приводит к ошибке выхода за пределы массива.